# No Class Def Found error android project to upload pictures

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am following [this tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/12/android-uploading-camera-image-video-to-server-with-progress-bar/) with a few modifications. I followed the instructions in a class and it's inheritance called `AndroidMultiPartEntity extends MultipartEntity`.

I have added the following jar files:

- mime4j
- httpclient-android-4.3.3
- httpcore
- httpmime

Some of these jars were added out of desperation to get rid of the error but however I am still receiving this error in my logcat:

> Caused by java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: package_name.AndroidMultiPartEntity

Output from the logcat:

```
06-29 01:25:05.720: E/AndroidRuntime(1770): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2
06-29 01:25:05.720: E/AndroidRuntime(1770): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
06-29 01:25:05.720: E/AndroidRuntime(1770):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
06-29 01:25:05.720: E/AndroidRuntime(1770):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
06-29 01:25:05.720: E/AndroidRuntime(1770):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
06-29 01:25:05.720: E/AndroidRuntime(1770):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
06-29 01:25:05.720: E/AndroidRuntime(1770):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
06-29 01:25:05.720: E/AndroidRuntime(1770):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
06-29 01:25:05.720: E/AndroidRuntime(1770):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
06-29 01:25:05.720: E/AndroidRuntime(1770):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
06-29 01:25:05.720: E/AndroidRuntime(1770):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
06-29 01:25:05.720: E/AndroidRuntime(1770): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.inc.automata.malawiscenery.util.AndroidMultiPartEntity
06-29 01:25:05.720: E/AndroidRuntime(1770):     at com.inc.automata.malawiscenery.UploadPictureActivity$UploadToServer.uploadFile(UploadPictureActivity.java:390)
06-29 01:25:05.720: E/AndroidRuntime(1770):     at com.inc.automata.malawiscenery.UploadPictureActivity$UploadToServer.doInBackground(UploadPictureActivity.java:359)
06-29 01:25:05.720: E/AndroidRuntime(1770):     at com.inc.automata.malawiscenery.UploadPictureActivity$UploadToServer.doInBackground(UploadPictureActivity.java:1)
06-29 01:25:05.720: E/AndroidRuntime(1770):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
06-29 01:25:05.720: E/AndroidRuntime(1770):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
```

Can anyone help me Identify exactly what I am doing wrong?
**UPDATE** information from the .classpath file:
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry exported="true" kind="con" path="com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ANDROID_FRAMEWORK"/>
    <classpathentry exported="true" kind="con" path="com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.LIBRARIES"/>
    <classpathentry exported="true" kind="con" path="com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.DEPENDENCIES"/>
    <classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="libs/volley.jar"/>
    <classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="libs/gson-2.2.4.jar"/>
    <classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="libs/metadata-extractor-2.6.4.jar"/>
    <classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="libs/android-support-v4.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="libs/httpmime-4.1.1.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="libs/httpclient-android-4.3.3.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="libs/httpcore-4.0.1.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="libs/mime4j-0.2.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="gen"/>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="bin/classes"/>
</classpath>`

Comment: Show your .classpath if you are using Eclipse or build.gradle if you are using Studio

Comment: added @HarishSridharan .what is the exact use of these files?

Comment: The .classpath file responsible for your ant compiler to give overall information about your project. The compiler uses these information for fetching source files and dependencies as defined here while compiling them. Only the libraries marked with exported=true will be packed along with your apk while the other references will be used by the compiler only at the compile time and the compiler will assume that these libraries  (not marked with exported=true) will be provided by default android system or any from sources at the run time and wont pack along with your apk.

Answer (score 0):

Add exported="true" for all the newly added libraries as given below. Your application only have compilation references to these libraries but not available at the runtime as you have not marked it **exported=true**. So these libraries won't available at run time causing you NoClassDefFoundError.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <classpath>
        <classpathentry exported="true" kind="con" path="com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ANDROID_FRAMEWORK"/>
        <classpathentry exported="true" kind="con" path="com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.LIBRARIES"/>
        <classpathentry exported="true" kind="con" path="com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.DEPENDENCIES"/>
        <classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="libs/volley.jar"/>
        <classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="libs/gson-2.2.4.jar"/>
        <classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="libs/metadata-extractor-2.6.4.jar"/>
        <classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="libs/android-support-v4.jar"/>
        <classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="libs/httpmime-4.1.1.jar"/>
        <classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="libs/httpclient-android-4.3.3.jar"/>
        <classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="libs/httpcore-4.0.1.jar"/>
        <classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="libs/mime4j-0.2.jar"/>
        <classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
        <classpathentry kind="src" path="gen"/>
        <classpathentry kind="output" path="bin/classes"/>
    </classpath>
```